# How to access one vagrant box from another via ssh?

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtual-machine

I use Vagrant 1.9.1 and boxes are config.vm.box = "centos/7". There seems to be private keys employed when calling „vagrant ssh“ to connect to a box. However, I’m not sure where are those keys located. Thanks a lot

Kind Regards
Diana

Answer (score 0):

You can run `vagrant ssh-config` command, for example

```
fhenri@machine:~/project/vagrant/centos$ vagrant ssh-config app1
Host app1
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /Users/fhenri/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

It will give you the information of the ssh key used